Repository of linear and nonlinear base functions for linear regression
is there any repository of linear and nonlinear base functions. I would like to compare some of them according to possibility to represent data. I think about a set as following:



Name
Dimension
Applications
Reference




Taylor series
1-n
...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series


Fourier series
1-n
Frequency problems (e.g. acoustics)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series


Spherical harmonics series
2
Radial problems
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics


...
...
...
...



Kr Simon
